# Java ECC Brainpool support for certificates?

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

Latest Version of Java did not support ECC Brainpool curves. When I read a X509Certificate containing a EC Curve Brainpool, I get an exception.

I found out that Java does not support certificates with Brainpool curves. Is there a way to add this support by myself?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a certificate (using base64 encoding or PEM?) I can probably write an answer, but this machine doesn't have any of those certificates ready to test.

Comment: Yes here it is one of these. I uploaded it here (http://pastebin.com/CAMPLMfx) in PEM, because it is to long for posting as comment.

Comment: OK, had to download the BC provider and munch some input, but the solution is relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bouncy Castle has support for these curves. The trick is that Java still has to know about them to find them. So you cannot just add the Bouncy Castle provider and be done with it. You need to use the `CertificateFactory` of Bouncy Castle explicitly.

If you just use the Java `CertificateFactory` you will be greeted with the following exception (which you are now probably familiar with):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Unknown named curve: 1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.7
```

So use the following code snippet / solution instead:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
// explicit BC factory required, knows about curve!
CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME); 
PemReader reader = new PemReader(new FileReader("ecc_certificate.txt"));
PemObject readPemObject = reader.readPemObject();
final byte[] cert = readPemObject.getContent();
Certificate generatedCertificate = fact.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(cert));
System.out.println(generatedCertificate);
```

To get the name of the named curve you however need to go to Bouncy Castle specific code (i.e. using the Bouncy classes directly instead of using them through the JCA):

```
ECPublicKey publicKey = (ECPublicKey) generatedCertificate.getPublicKey();
// Bouncy Castle specific class
ECNamedCurveSpec params = (ECNamedCurveSpec) publicKey.getParams();
System.out.println(params.getName());
```

Almost forgot: you need both the Bouncy Castle provider *and* the PKIX jar file in your classpath to do this.

Downloading the unlimited crypto files for Java never hurts either, although it probably is not directly needed for this functionality (better safe than sorry though). For newer Java versions this may not be required anymore.

Comment: thanks! Adding BC Provder to Security and to CertificateFactory did work like i want it :) Thanks! one other Question: if i print out the key.getParameters() i don't get the name of the curve (here: brainpoolP256r1), with the old original java code i get the name from other EC Curves, but now i got only: org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec@4af0acaf - any idea?

Comment: OK fixed that as well, but you need Bouncy specific code for that.

Answer (score 1):

EC Curve Brainpool has been disabled in Java 15 ([issue](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8251547)) and removed after Java 15. The solution is to add a third-party library like [bcprov-jdk15on](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on). Then you just need to indicate the provider. Example:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); // load third-party lib
Signature SHA256 = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "BC"); // use BC provider
```

With these 2 lines you get rid of the "Legacy SunEC curve disabled" on Java 15 and "Curve not supported" exception in Java >15. More info [here](https://www.java.com/en/configure_crypto.html). And details on how to use Java Bouncy Castle in [baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bouncy-castle).